# Running pytest to assert output of an entire script

Tags: python-2.7, testing, pytest

After testing a script's functions separately with pytest, I'd like to test several use-cases by supplying command-line arguments and letting it run in its entirety. Then I'd like to compare the output with my expected output. Can I do this via pytest?

If I can't do this to an entire script via command-line input, I'd have to mock argparse. Can you point me to which is the best approach? Thanks!

```
Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy, you just have to structure correctly:

```
def main():
    # argument parsing stuff here
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now in your tests call `main()` function directly.  It is *not* necessary to run a separate python process.  To simulate the argument parsing, you just have to patch `sys.argv`.  If your script relies on any config files or environment variables, you'll have to mock/patch those too.

Comment: As you suggested, `monkeypatch.setattr(sys, 'argv', my_arg_list)`, called my main-function and it worked. Thanks!